# Mondrian MDX Query, Avoid Fatal Error when Member not Found in cube

Tags: olap, mdx, mondrian

i want to know if is it possible to avoid mondrian´s fatal error when it doesn't have any member in defined cube. for instance i have this MDX Query

select {[Measures].[Unit_Sales], [Measures].[Quantity], [Measures].[Total]} ON COLUMNS,
Hierarchize({([Country.CountryHeirarchy].[All Countries].[USA], [Products.ProductHeirarchy].[All Products])}) ON ROWS
from [SALES]

and lets say, the DataBase doesn't have the USA member, i want to get a zero(0) or null value. is it possible to do that on mondrian.

i have been trying with this property in **mondrian.property** file

**mondrian.rolap.ignoreInvalidMembersDuringQuery=true**

but not lucky still now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should try setting this in mondrian.properties file and make sure this file loaded during server start.

```
mondrian.rolap.ignoreInvalidMembers=true
```

**Description for above setting:** "Boolean property indicating whether errors related to non-existent members
should be ignored during schema load. If so, the non-existent member is 
treated as a null member."

Answer (score -1):

REPLACE YOUR ".galleria-stage" CLASS IN "galleria.classic.css" WITH

```
.galleria-stage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

and you will see the right output in IE and other browsers.

Comment: unrelated to question.